# how to remove background from a leaflet interactive map in the shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Within Shiny context, I have created the below pretty map. I was wondering to know how can I remove the background (e.g., Mexico, Canada, Oceans) in such a way that only US states appear. I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
    .leaflet-tile-container {
    display: none;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't with your current tiles. You have to find a tile server which only shows the USA

Comment: I believe you are referring to this part of my code: addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron"). How can I find the server you are referring to.

Comment: Actually, I can. What I needed was to add an option as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I needed! Adding an option to set the opacity to 0.

```
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",
                  options = providerTileOptions(opacity = 0)) %>%
                  addTiles(none)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just removed:

```
addTiles() %>%
```

It removed the background. But be forewarned I am new to `leaflet` so this is probably not a solid solution.